# how to create android app with no launcher icon? but it can be opened from android command terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal

I have tried to remove this line but it won't open from android terminal

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: Try replacing it with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />` Make sure you didn't remove `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`.

Comment: thanx man. It is working.